# Qt : draw triangle image

Tags: qt, drawimage, qpainter

I need to do something similar to `QPainter::drawImage`, but drawing a triangle part of the given picture (into a triangular region of my widget) instead of working with rectangles.

Any idea how I could do that, besides painfully trying to redraw every pixel?

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is feasible for you to use a QPixmap instead of a QImage, you can [set a bitmap mask](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#setMask) for the QPixmap which defines which of the pixels are shown and which are transparent:

```
myPixmap->setMask(myTriangleMask);
painter->drawPixmap(myPixmap);
```

Here is another solution based on QImage:

```
MaskWidget::MaskWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {
   img = QImage("Sample.jpg");     // The image to paint
   mask = QImage("Mask.png");      // An indexed 2-bit colormap image
   QPainter imgPainter(&img);
   imgPainter.drawImage(0, 0, mask);  // Paint the mask onto the image
}

void MaskWidget::paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event ) {
   QPainter painter(this);
   painter.drawImage(10, 10, img);
}
```

Mask.png is an image file with the same size as Sample.jpg. It contains an alpha channel to support transparency. You can create this file easily with The GIMP, for example. I added an alpha channel, changed all areas I want to have painted to transparent and all other areas to white. To reduce the size, I finally converted it to an indexed 2-bit image.
You could even create the mask image programmatically with Qt, if you need your triangle be computed based on various parameters.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'll look this up and come back here.

Comment: Hi there again, thanks again for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to work very well for what I want to do. First because I would want to define the triangle mask programmatically indeed and it might be tricky. Secondly because I want to draw thousands of triangles so I need to do something very efficient. I guess I should have asked a more precise question, I might do that soon, I apologize for taking up some of your time, well, you told me something potentially useful anyway :)